# typerror: not a function error even when function exists

Tags: node.js

Consider the following code:

```
//database/team.js

const getId = (teamname, callback) => {
  Team.findOne({name: teamname}, (err, doc) => {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, doc._id);
  });
}

console.log(typeof getId);

module.exports = {
  'getId': getId
}
```

I use this function in a different file as follows:

```
//folder/file.js

const team = require('../database/team');

const xyz = (arg1, arg2, callback) => {
  //do stuff here
  team.getId(name, (err, result) => {
    callback(stuff)
  }
}

console.log(typeof team.getId);

module.exports = {
  'xyz': xyz
}
```

I use this function within a route but I get the following error:

TypeError: team.getId is not a function

Both console.log statements output 'function'

Any help will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: it should be `const team = require('./database/team');` // one dot instead of two

Comment: @RahulSingh I don't think so, given the paths.

Comment: I guess the problem is in the part of the files we don't see.

Comment: @DenysSéguret it might be denys

Comment: There are other functions in team.js (which work absolutely fine btw) and obviously there is some application logic in file.js (all of which resides within the callback of team.getId) but I found those details to be irrelevant to the question

Comment: You're missing some very relevant "details". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve